# How to use twitter bootstrap using assetic and less in symfony2?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, symfony, less, assetic

I can't get twitter bootstrap working. I know there is many tutorials and so on, but none of it works for me...

My composer.json is:

```
"require":
    [...]
    "leafo/lessphp": "dev-master",
    "braincrafted/bootstrap-bundle": "dev-master",
    "twbs/bootstrap": "2.3.*"
```

My assetic configuration is:

```
# Assetic Configuration
assetic:
    filters:
        lessphp:
            file: %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/leafo/lessphp/lessc.inc.php
            apply_to: "\.less$"
        cssrewrite: ~
    assets:
        bootstrap_css:
            inputs:
                - %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less
                - %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/less/responsive.less
            filters:
                - lessphp
                - cssrewrite
            output: css/bootstrap.css
        bootstrap_js:
            inputs:
                - %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/js/bootstrap-transition.js
                - %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/js/bootstrap-alert.js
                - %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/js/bootstrap-button.js
                - %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/js/bootstrap-carousel.js
                - %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/js/bootstrap-collapse.js
                - %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/js/bootstrap-dropdown.js
                - %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/js/bootstrap-modal.js
                - %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/js/bootstrap-tooltip.js
                - %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/js/bootstrap-popover.js
                - %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/js/bootstrap-scrollspy.js
                - %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/js/bootstrap-tab.js
                - %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/js/bootstrap-typeahead.js
                - %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/js/bootstrap-affix.js
            output: js/bootstrap.js
```

And finally `::base.html.twig`:

```
{% block stylesheets %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/bootstrap.css') }}">
{% endblock %}

{% block javascripts %}
    <script src="{{ asset('js/bootstrap.js') }}"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

I'm trying include js ans css with different ways, for example:

```
{% stylesheets '%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less' %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
{% endstylesheets %}
```

or

```
{% stylesheets '@bootstrap_css' %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
{% endstylesheets %}
```

but it still not working and I'm getting 404 errors for bootstrap.css and bootstrap.js.

Whats wrong with my config? I'm using wamp server on windows 7 64bit.

The only way to get it working was to use cli command `assetic:dump` but I think it's not correct way to do this on dev environment.

Comment: I'm not really sure but it seems you have to call the *assetic:dump* command to generate the new css and js files. They have to be merged together that you have only a single file.

Comment: When I do so then it generates many js and css files (in fact they are listed in assetic `inputs` section) and makes a little mess. I thought that if I'm using assetic and less then it's enought to call `<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/bootstrap.css') }}">` as it's defined in assetic `output` section and `bootstrap.css` will be generated.

Comment: It creates many files because you're running it on your dev-environment, should you run the command ``assetic:dump --env=prod`` you'll notice there will be less files

Comment: @exepti0n, @sensi Ok, but one thing - I have red several tutorials, bootstrap doc also, but there was no mension about using `assetic:dump` (see [http://bootstrap.braincrafted.com/getting-started](http://bootstrap.braincrafted.com/getting-started) so even if it works after this command I thing this is not proper solution.

Comment: Are the files properly generated in your web-folder?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally I've used simply js and css files from bootstrap, without any bundle in symfony because it's faster, easier and may have some advantages such as any update of bootstrap will not crash my site (see update bootstrap 2 to 3...).

So thanks to all for your answers but this is for me best solution.

Comment: So did you just include the Bootstrap CSS in your `/css` directory and then reference that in your `{% stylesheets %}` section. Can you post the code? I have pretty much the same problem as you, although I would prefer to leverage the benefits of Assetic.

Comment: Yeah, I've just copy `css` and `js` files into `web` and reference it directly in template. It's pretty lame, but unfortunately that was the only solution for me. But that was when I've used Windows so that could be some OS related issue.

Comment: I'll try it out later and see how it goes, but I am keen to get `lessphp` and Assetic working with Bootstrap.

Comment: Yes, I guess this is the easiest way to import a theme but I am still keen to get it working with LESS and Bootstrap. I can confirm this simplistic approach does work though.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your config_dev.yml:

```
assetic:
    use_controller: true
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this was in `config_dev.yml` by default and I didn't change it.

Answer (score 0):

So here is the final answer to your issue:

You have to run it manual because of performance impact. Otherwise if you use to much filters it takes to long to load the app and that can be really frustrating.

In older versions of symfony it seems it was done automatic but have now removed.

See documentation: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html#dumping-asset-files-in-the-dev-environment

So everything is ok with your code and configuration.